# C++ clr Hosting - ICLRMetaHost GetRuntime уточнение версии до 4.7.2

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr

При использовании конфигурации `app.exe.config` можно указать желательную версию clr, например:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
```

Как то же самое уточнить для объекта `ICLRMetaHost`->`GetRuntime(..)` ?

В примерах примерно следующее:

```
 iclrMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v4.0.30319", IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo));
```

Какой синтаксис для параметра `sku` по аналогии с файлом конфигурации?
Версия `v4.0.30319` как я понимаю базовая, и включает все ветки от 4.0 до 4.7.2 на текущий момент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого синтаксиса нет, потому что это несколько разные вещи. Метод `GetRuntime` принимает на вход именно **версию CLR**, а не версию .NET Framework. Все версии .NET 4.x используют одну и ту же версию CLR, v4.0.30319. Параметр `sku` в конфигурации, напротив, уточняет именно **версию .NET Framework**; это делается для того, чтобы в случае, когда приложение требует определенную минорную версию из набора версий 4.x, при ее отсутствии стандартный загрузчик CLR мог вывести пользователю осмысленное сообщение "Установите такую-то версию", а не просто упасть.

Если вы делаете свой загрузчик, похоже, подобный функционал придется реализовать самостоятельно, считывая версии установленных .NET из реестра и сравнивая с требуемой. Однако, судя по соседству v2.x и v4.x, вы пытаетесь сделать приложение, которое совместимо с обеими версиями и не использует никаких новшеств v4.х, поэтому этот параметр вам вовсе не нужен.

Конфигурацию для этого случая можно упростить:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
```

И соответствующий код инициализации CLR будет выглядеть так:

```
hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v4.0.30319", IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo)); 

if (FAILED(hr)) hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v2.0.50727", IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo)); 

if (FAILED(hr)) { 
    printf("Failed to initialize CLR: HRESULT 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)hr ); 
    exit(); 
}
```